# how to import or include another yml file in a yml for mulesoft manifest

Tags: yaml, manifest, mulesoft

I am using global-sub.yml as mulesoft manifest which is inherited from a global.yml. now i want to import or include another yml file. such as db2.yml or oracle.yml in global-sub.yml. I tried several patterns but always failed. how to make it happen?

for example of my global-sub.yml

```
inherit: ../global.yml

env:
 xxx: xxx
 yyy: yyy
```

Comment: To what manifest are you referring? Do you mean a configuration property yaml filehttps://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/configuring-properties#supported_files)?

Comment: Hi Ale, It is not the properties file in source code. After review it that i think i made a mistake. it should be yml file for cloud foundry which is used to deploy an API instance. I can see  we are using such yml files to define environment variables for an instance. But it is always failed to import or include another yml file in a yml. So do you have any idea on this? Thanks for your support.